# Java: Making own annotation that highlights methods and adds custom messaging

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have some importand methods in code that are used in a wrong way, people don't get the whole context of the process and invokes wrong methods, for example setters. If I had something like @Deprecated it could highlight / strike/ underline methods and show som info when somebody uses it. For example someone set some variables that are even not persisted as he thought that it would persist. Another person changed one method and spoiled dozen of usecases becaouse he didnt know about them..

I use Java7 and IntelliJ Idea 14

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an annotation, program defensively, check if the parameters you get make sense. Write tests to verify what happens when invalid input is provided.

I think Automated Tests, Good Method Names and such will do more good than some fancy IDE plugin to stop other developers from invoking wrong methods.

Comment: Ok but still I would like to write plugin to Idea, it would be fun, maybe someone already seen something like that? Source code?